# Sheet wont dismiss if item changed while animating

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5.7

I'm running XCode Beta 14.0 beta 3 although i dont think that's the issue.

I have an app that has custom callbacks based on an AVCaptureSession in a dynamic Library called Engine. The enum/protocol listed below:

```
public enum EngineState {
    case initializing
    case running
    case ready
    case error
}
```

```
public protocol EngineStateDelegate {
    func onEngineState(state: EngineState)
}
```

On my front end, when I initialize the AVCaptureSession the first time and the delegates get called, the sheets update as they should, but when re-initialize it, the delegates get called and the sheet doesnt dismiss. My guess is that it doesnt dismiss because the animation is still happening but i'm not sure.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {
            // extra code here
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $viewModel.sheetIdentifier) { sheet in
            sheet.get()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sheetIdentifier: MainViewSheetModel? = .init(id: .initializing)
    // --- other parts here ---
}

extension MainViewModel: EngineStateDelegate {
    func onEngineState(state: EngineState) {
        switch (state) {
        case .initializing, .ready:
            sheetIdentifier = .init(id: .initializing)
        case .running:
            self.sheetIdentifier = nil
        case .error:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MainViewSheetModel: Identifiable {
    enum Sheets {
        case audioInterrupted
        case videoInterrupted
        case ipadInterrupted
        case pressureInterrupted
        case mediaServicesReset
        case runtimeError
        case streamStatus
        case initializing
        case other
    }
    
    var id: Sheets
    var message1: String
    var message2: String
    var progressSpinner: Bool
    
    //: DEFAULTS
    private struct internalSheetModel {
        var message1: String
        var message2: String
        var progressSpinner: Bool
    }
    
    private let SheetModelData: [Sheets: internalSheetModel] = [
        .audioInterrupted: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "Your camera/mic are unavailable. Waiting for them to become usable.",
            message2: "If you are playing music in the background, pause it to resume.",
            progressSpinner: true),
        .videoInterrupted: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "Restarting Video System ... ",
            message2: "",
            progressSpinner: true),
        .ipadInterrupted: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "The Camera is not usable in Split View.",
            message2: "Please open the app by itself.",
            progressSpinner: false),
        .pressureInterrupted: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "The device is too hot to use the camera/mic.",
            message2: "Please try again later.",
            progressSpinner: false),
        .mediaServicesReset: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "Media Services Reset",
            message2: "Restarting Camera Engine",
            progressSpinner: true),
        .runtimeError: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "The camera/mic system crashed.",
            message2: "Please contact support if the problem persists.",
            progressSpinner: false),
        .streamStatus: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "Stream Status",
            message2: "",
            progressSpinner: true),
        .initializing: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "Initializing the Camera Engine",
            message2: "",
            progressSpinner: true),
        .other: internalSheetModel(
            message1: "",
            message2: "",
            progressSpinner: true)
    ]
    
    //: BODY
    init() {
        self.id = .other
        self.message1 = ""
        self.message2 = ""
        self.progressSpinner = false
    }
    
    init(id: Sheets) {
        self.id = id
        self.message1 = SheetModelData[id]?.message1 ?? ""
        self.message2 = SheetModelData[id]?.message2 ?? ""
        self.progressSpinner = SheetModelData[id]?.progressSpinner ?? false
    }
    
    init(id: Sheets = .other, message1: String, message2: String, progressSpinner: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.message1 = message1
        self.message2 = message2
        self.progressSpinner = progressSpinner
    }
    
    //: Internal View
    struct InternalSheetView: View {
        var message1: String
        var message2: String
        var progressSpinner: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.opacity(0.0)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack(spacing: 24) {
                    if (progressSpinner) {
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                            .scaleEffect(2)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    
                    if (!message1.isEmpty) {
                        Text(message1)
                    }
                    
                    if (!message2.isEmpty) {
                        Text(message2)
                    }
                } //: VStack
            } //: ZStack
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .background(
                BackgroundBlurView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            )
        }
    }
    
    func get() -> some View {
        return InternalSheetView(message1: message1, message2: message2, progressSpinner: progressSpinner)
    }
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** How do I make sure the view disappears without user interaction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could do it by using @Bind a bool value to your sub sheet, then make the value false depends on your process result.

Comment: MainViewSheetModel should be a struct so it’s contents modification be published.

Comment: Observation, since your `MainViewModel` has `@Published` and you want to be observable, you should declare it as `ObservableObject` as well. In addition, you probably should have `@StateObject` for it in your `MainView`

Comment: @tail i was trying to avoid that since i have many different sheets and nmore than one place can control the boolean, but you may be right

Comment: @PtitXav You're right ... it is a struct, i added the code so it's clear

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine You're right ... it correct in the code i just didnt make it clear here. I updated the post to clarify. Thanks for calling that out.

Comment: The problem may be that now you published struct is an optional : it is only published when created not when its contents is modified. That is like publishing a pointer, only the address contains in the pointer is published, not what the address points to.

Comment: If you do not want to pass your model everywhere you could use an environment object that you pass to the main view, then all descendant views can use it.

Comment: I found out the problem was actually my camera was trying to open a sheet when the app lost focus and since a sheet was already opened it was erroring me out. Thanks for everyone's help, going to mark this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was actually my camera was trying to open a sheet when the app lost focus and since a sheet was already opened it was erroring.